# Can't delete file with strange characters in name

Tags: terminal, finder

I have an old file named `ˇ¡␀␀ˇ¡␀␀␀"9 ␀"9` which is not deleted when I empty the trash. I have tried renaming it but it does not accept any changes. Using the Terminal didn't work either so far:

```
Mac-Pro:deletethisfolder me$ find . -inum 425884608 -delete
find: -delete: rmdir(./ˇ¡␀␀ˇ¡␀␀␀"9\006␀"9): Invalid argument
```

what can I do? Thanks!

Comment: What about `find . -inum 425884608 -exec rm -fir {} \;`?

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work either:

`$find . -inum 425884608 -exec rm -fir {} \;`
`examine files in directory ./ˇ¡␀␀ˇ¡␀␀␀"9␀"9?`

`$ rmdir ˇ¡␀␀ˇ¡␀␀␀\"9^F␀\"9/`
`rmdir: ˇ¡␀␀ˇ¡␀␀␀"9\006␀"9/: Invalid argument`

Comment: @MateuszSzlosek Also I booted with 10.6 and emptied the trash. It seemed to work until I booted with 10.11 and the file was back in the trash again. So maybe it's no a 10.11 issue. (see last response on the other threat, unfortunately I cannot yet comment)